# firebase is not working with with polymer 3.0

Tags: firebase, polymer, firebase-authentication, polymerfire

I was using polymerfire with polymer 2.0. However, then I decided to move to polymer 3.0. I tried to use this element https://www.npmjs.com/package/polymerfire3. But it doesn't work. It kept on giving an error

> Cannot read property 'signInWithPopup' of undefined
>       at HTMLElement.signInWithPopup (firebase-auth.js:200)

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: this means firebase.auth() is not defined. Have you initialised your firebase app before?

Comment: Yes. I have been using firebase in polymer 2 for more than an year. Somehow it is working with polymer 3. I am looking for a sample app with firebase with polymer 3 use case, could not find it